# J2 visa renewal

Tags: usa, j-visa

My husband's J2 visa expired and he has a valid job permit until Dec 2017. Our DS-2019 is also valid until DEC 2017. My question is, can he renew his visa inside the US? Or he has to go back to Venezuela in order to do so? Is it possible for him to renew that visa somewhere else? Like Mexico or Canada which are closer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me why he wants to renew his visa. A US visa is solely for entering the US. He needs to renew his visa only if he needs to re-enter the US in J-2 status. He cannot get a US visa inside the US, because, if he is already in the US, then he doesn't need to enter. The next time he leaves the US, if he wants to re-enter in J-2 status, then he will need to apply for a J-2 visa at a US consulate in whatever country he will be in.